# Proving a set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with a certain property is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ be a set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ with the following property: for each $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ there exists a function $g \in A$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists an $m \geq n$ with $f(m)<g(m)$. Prove that $A$ is uncountable.

Does anyone have an idea? I thought to suppose $A$ is countable (so there is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$) and then try to have a contradiction, but I don't know how.

Comment: To the person who closed this question as a duplicate: none of the three linked questions which supposedly answer this actually do - this question is not about proving that the set of all functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable, but rather a specific subset of it. None of the linked questions answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A$ was countable, and let $\{g_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an enumeration of it. Define $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ by

$$f(j)=\max_{0\leq i\leq j}g_i(j)+1.$$

Now using the definition of $A$ we can find a $g_n\in A$ such that

$$f(m)<g_n(m)$$

for some $m\geq n$. But

$$f(m)>g_n(m)$$

by definition, and so we have a contradiction.

Comment: You cannot use the definition of $A$ for $f$ without showing $f \in A$ first. In fact, that is not true, as you show later.

Comment: @GuusB I never claim that $f\in A$ though. The definition of $A$ simple guarantees that I can find the $g_n$ I need, regardless of what $f$ I choose

Comment: If you want to show that $A$ is uncountable, you need to find an $f \in A$ that is not equal to any of the $g_i$, given any enumeration $\{g_i\}_i$ of $A$. You need $f \in A$!

Comment: @GuusB no I don't. All I need is to assume $A$ is countable and get a contradiction. It does not matter what this contradiction is.

Comment: Let's apply the same logic to a simpler case: "Suppose $\pi$ is irrational. Consider $2 \pi$. By the definition of rational numbers, $2\pi = a / b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$. But then $\pi = a / (2b)$, which is rational. Contradiction! Hence $\pi$ must be rational!" This doesn't work because you cannot use the property of rationality to just any real number. Yes, we arrive at a contradiction, but not to the original premise.

Here too, you must first make sure $f \in A$ before you can apply the definition of $A$ to $f$. Please take a critical look at your proof.

Comment: @GuusB Did you even read the original question? You don't seem to understand how $A$ is defined. **I am at no point claiming or using that $f$ would be an element of $A$, it is just a function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$.** What I'm doing is perfectly allowed, and your analogy literally makes no sense.

Comment: It indeed appears I have misread the question. My sincere apologies for being so stubborn.

Comment: I am not sure why we can't find a $g(m) > f(m)$ for some $m \ge n$ according to your construction. By your definition, $f(m)$ is the largest value among the first $m + 1$ $g_i(m)$ plus 1. It seems to me that it is still possible to find $g_i(m) > f(m)$ for some $i > m$. Perhaps we can instead define $f(j) = \max g_i(j) + 1$?